# Migration from Tomcat6 to Tomcat7 - get jsp error "property attribute is no valid value reference: org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression@1ccd88d7"

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat7

I am working with:

- jdk6
- tomcat6
- jsf 1.2

I need to upgrade:

- jdk7
- tomcat7
- jsf 2.2

I started upgrading to jdk7 and tomcat7, 
The server start but I am getting the following error message:

```
 property attribute is no valid value reference: org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression@1ccd88d7
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page *.jsp at line 207
206:        <a4j:jsFunction name="deleteFile" action="#{documentUploadControl.deleteFile}" reRender="fileListDiv,buttonsDiv">
207:             <a4j:actionparam name="param1" assignTo="#{documentUploadControl.deleteFileIndex}" /> 
208:        </a4j:jsFunction>
```

The page works properly with tomcat6.

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you modify your application to adopt Facelets constructs in JSF 2.2? According to the exception, you did not. Please do it. Legacy JSP in JSF 1.x is not supported since JSF 2.x.

Comment: I just replaced the JDK6 to JDK7 and the Tomcat6 to Tomcat7.
I do not change JSF settings, now it still JSF1.2,
I need to replace it all together?

Comment: @Tiny Your source for that assertion please. I'm using both.

Comment: @EJP : It was my mistake replacing "*deprecated*" with/by "*not supported*", sorry. To be a disclaimer, I never used JSF 1.x.